# Is the order of adjectives correct?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-order

Is the order of adjectives correct?

> "**Delicate golden body**"
>
> "Then something **small, golden and fierce** jumped on Allen’s body"

Comment: There's not *really* any strict order of adjectives, but I'm inclined to change the second to *fierce, small and golden*.

Comment: @DogLover Doing so so changes the emphasis (in meaning, not pronunciation), which is is slightly stronger for the last adjective.

Comment: Ah, I see that that's already explained in LaurenceC's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only hard rule with adjectives would be the following:

- determiners must come first, if you are using them.  Articles, possessive pronouns, words such as *this*, *that*, *these*, *those*, and any word that answers "how many" - such as numbers - all fall in that category.
- If you use a number and other type of determiner, the number comes after the other word.

> I took 3 old blue pens from the container.
>
> I took old blue 3 pens from the container (bad).
>
> I took these 3 old blue pens from the container.
>
> I took my 3 old blue pens from the container.
>
> I took old these 3 blue pens from the container (bad).

You may be able to get away with not saying the number in the proper spot when talking, but never other determiners.

The link @Mohammad Chamanpara provides should be followed, but you may see the order not followed strictly.  When using 3 or more adjectives, the adjectives closer to the word are slightly emphasized, so a writer may choose to move a more "important" adjective closer to the word being modified.

> Then something small, golden and fierce jumped on Allen’s body"

*Fierce* here sticks out as slightly more important or prominent than *small* or *golden*.

> Then something fierce, golden, and small jumped on Allen's body"

Here *small* is a bit more important than *fierce* or *golden*.

You would probably have to hear someone read it loud in a dramatic fashion for what I'm saying to make complete sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct. 
I don't think it matters.

> Delicate golden body

is the same as

> Golden delicate body

and "

> Then something small, golden and fierce jumped on Allen’s body"

is the same as "

> Then something small, fierce and golden and fierce jumped on Allen’s
>   body"

or as

> "Then something golden, fierce and golden and fierce jumped on Allen’s
>   body"

Answer (score 0):

The order of adjectives :

> 1. General opinion
> 2. Specific opinion
> 3. Size
> 4. Shape
> 5. Age
> 6. Color
> 7. Nationality
> 8. Material

You can see [this](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/order-adjectives) link for some information on this topic.
I hope this is helpful.